# Front end form with Matrix won't add more than one row

Tags: craft3, matrix, frontend-form

I have Notification entry with sendTo field and nViewed matrix:
- viewedBy = Users field, limit of 1
- viewedDateTime = Plain Text

User's don't see whole front end form, just a 'Mark as Read' link. The link uses js to populate viewedDateTime and submit form. My form:

```
<form id="update-{{ msg.id }}" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   {{ csrfInput() }}
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry" />
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ theredirect }}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="{{ msg.section.id }}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ msg.id }}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="fields[nViewed]" />
   <input type="hidden" name="fields[nViewed][new1][type]" value="viewed" />
   <input type="hidden" name="fields[nViewed][new1][enabled]" value="1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="fields[nViewed][new1][fields][viewedBy][]" value="{{ currentUser.id }}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="fields[nViewed][new1][fields][viewedDateTime]" value="" />
   <button type="submit" class="tx-11 btn bd-0">Mark as read</button>
</form>
```

When the first user from sentTo clicks the 'Mark as Read' link, they get added to the matrix. All good.

When the second user from sentTo (testing on a different browser) clicks the 'Mark as Read' link it overwrites the first users row instead of adding another row to matrix.

I've also tried using field `name="fields[nViewed][new{{ currentUser.id }}]...` to make them unique but still overwrites.

What am I missing?
Amanda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the craft cms docs

> To show a “New Block” form, first come up with a temporary ID for the
>   block, prefixed with new:. For example, new:1, new:2, etc.

so, you need to you use prefix `new:` with the colon is a must.

Comment: Still no. Even made sure I upgraded from 3.4.0 to 3.4.14. Tried both [new:{{ currentUser.id }}] and [new:1]. Can you please link to craft docs? I can't find that page.

Comment: This is the page of craft docs,  https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/matrix-fields.html#templating

Comment: Classic case of RTFM.